# Selenium Check Url

Tags: selenium-webdriver, url, selenium-chromedriver, substring

I am using the Chrome Selenium IDE extension for some basic tests on my web application.

This is how I get the current URL of the page:
[image]

And this is where I assert that the URL is "abc123.com".
However, the issue is that the URL has a token parameter like "abc123.com?token=6454545" hence I get the error stating that "abc123.com" does not equal "abc123?token=6454545".

Is it possible to get a substring of the URL in Selenium?

Comment: Selenium has a built-in method for this getCurrentURL(), but it probably does the same thing.  You can parse the returned value by splitting on "?".  That should remove any query params.  (btw, using tokens on a GET can be a bad idea if they are meant to be private... they can show up in server logs.)